# Wrap nested object of functions in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I'm using Redux and have broken up the store data into "slices". Each "slice" corresponds to an area such as `users` or `comments`. I combine the selectors for each of these slices into one top-level `selectors` module which I access throughout the application.

A slice is of the format:

```
export interface IUsersSelectors {
  getCurrentUser(state: IUsersState): IUser | undefined;
}

const selectors: IUsersSelectors = {
  getCurrentUser(state: IUsersState) {
    return state.currentUser;
  }
};

export default {
  getInitialState,
  reducer,
  selectors
};
```

Which are then all imported, and the selectors combined:

```
export const selectors = Object.keys(slices).reduce((combinedSelectors: any, sliceKey: string) => {
  const sliceSelectors = slices[sliceKey].selectors;

  combinedSelectors[sliceKey] = Object.keys(sliceSelectors).reduce((selectorsMap: object, selectorKey: string) => {
    const localizedSelector = sliceSelectors[selectorKey];

    selectorsMap[selectorKey] = (globalState, ...args: any[]): any => {
      return localizedSelector(globalState[sliceKey], ...args);
    };

    return selectorsMap;
  }, {});

  return combinedSelectors;
}, {});
```

And then used throughout the app:

```
selectors.users.getCurrentUser(store.getState());
```

This means that selectors *expect* just their slice state when retrieving the data, but they're actually *invoked* with the global store state. I'm essentially just wrapping them in another function that manages the scoping.

The closest I've gotten to defining generic types for this is:

```
type IScopedSelector<T extends () => any> = (globalState: IStoreState, ...args: any[]) => ReturnType<T>;

type IScopedSelectors<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: IScopedSelector<T[K]>;
};

type INestedScopedSelectors<R> = {
  [S in keyof R]: IScopedSelectors<R[S]>;
};

export const selectors: INestedScopedSelectors<ISelectors>...
```

where `ISelectors` is a simple interface of the shape:

```
export interface ISelectors {
  users: IUsersSelectors;
}
```

However, I get an error with this typing when trying to pass `T[K]` to `IScopedSelector` since it has to be a function:

```
[ts] Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '() => any'.
```

If I remove the `extends () => any`, then I get an error about `ReturnType`:

```
[ts] Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
```

Ideally, I'd also maintain the typing of the selector parameters as well (rather than `...args: any[]`), only overriding the first argument to be the global store state.

Is there a better way to handle nested generics like this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a similar type constraint to the generic type for both `IScopedSelectors` and `INestedScopedSelectors`.

Without such a constraint, you've told TypeScript that the `T` in `IScopedSelectors<T>` can be any type. So `IScopedSelectors<string>` should be valid. But TypeScript rightly points out that for many types (such as `string`), `[K in keyof T]: IScopedSelector<T[K]>` won't work since there is no guarantee that `T[K]` adheres to the constraint imposed by `IScopedSelector`.

So the solution is just to add a constraint to both interfaces so that TypeScript has that guarantee. For that, the built in `Record` type might be helpful. So something like:

```
type IScopedSelectors<T extends Record<string, () => any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: IScopedSelector<T[K]>; // T[K] is now guaranteed to adhere to () => any
};

type INestedScopedSelectors<R extends Record<string, Record<string, () => any>>> = {
  [S in keyof R]: IScopedSelectors<R[S]>; // Similarly, R[S] is now guaranteed to adhere to Record<string, () => any>, exactly what IScopedSelectors is expecting.
};
```

You may want to replace the `Record` types with something more specific depending on your exact use case, but the solution is essentially the same. Just make sure to forward your constraint all the way up the hierarchy.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think that makes sense in theory. However, I then get an error when trying to pass the `ISelectors` interface to `INestedScopedSelectors`: `Type 'ISelectors' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, Record<string, () => any>>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'ISelectors'.` I imagine I need the `Record` type somewhere in `ISelectors`, but not sure what that looks like since the interface is just a simple mapping?

Comment: You can remove the need for an index signature by using an inline mapped type instead. So `T extends {[K in keyof T]: () => any}` and `R extends {[S in keyof R]: {[K in keyof R[S]]: () => any}}` respectively. But then typescript points out another issue, namely that: *Types of property 'getCurrentUser' are incompatible, Type `(state: IUsersState) => IUser | undefined` not assignable to `() => any`*. You can fix that by using `(...args: any[]) => any` instead of `() => any`, but I'm not sure if that's too permissible of a type for your use case. LMK.

Comment: that worked! I do lose the typing of all the args after `globalState`, but unless you have any ideas for addressing that then this is still vastly better than no typing at all. Thanks!